# DataTables search and filter by Group?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables and I am grouping the table as well. The first column is and ID which can be neglected. I am using select inputs to give the users the possibility to filter the table.

However, cause nobody needs to filter by the id I want to give the users the possibility to filter also by the groups. That means I have to replace the option values  of the id select input with the groups and filter the groups instead of the ids when select the dropdown on the id column.

I hope you guys got me. 
I just want to replace the first select option values with the available groups and give the possibility to filter by groups as well.

Here is an example of my table:

```js
var table;
var groupColumn = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {

  table = $('#contact_overview_table').DataTable({
    "displayStart": 0,
    "language": {
      "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/German.json"
    },
    "columnDefs": [{
      "visible": false,
      "targets": groupColumn
    }],
    "order": [
      [groupColumn, 'asc']
    ],
    "processing": true,
    "pageLength": 25,
    "drawCallback": function(settings) {
      var api = this.api();
      var rows = api.rows({
        page: 'current'
      }).nodes();
      var last = null;

      api.column(groupColumn, {
        page: 'current'
      }).data().each(function(group, i) {
        if (last !== group) {
          $(rows).eq(i).before(
            '<tr class="group"><td colspan="15" style="font-weight: bold;">' + group + '</td></tr>'
          );

          last = group;
        }
      });
    },
    initComplete: function() {
      this.api().columns().every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
          .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
          .on('change', function() {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
              $(this).val()
            );

            column
              .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
        });
      });
    },
  });

  // Order by the grouping
  $('#contact_overview_table tbody').on('click', 'tr.group', function() {
    var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
    if (currentOrder[0] === groupColumn && currentOrder[1] === 'asc') {
      table.order([groupColumn, 'desc']).draw();
    } else {
      table.order([groupColumn, 'asc']).draw();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<div id="contact_overview_table_div" class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="contact_overview_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">ID</th>
        <th class="text-center">Art</th>
        <th class="text-center">Anrede</th>
        <th class="text-center">Titel</th>
        <th class="text-center">Vorname</th>
        <th class="text-center">Name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Firma</th>
        <th class="text-center">Straße</th>
        <th class="text-center">Ort</th>
        <th class="text-center">Mobil</th>
        <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Porf</th>
        <th>Max</th>
        <th>Müller</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Berlin</th>
        <th>+21 431 8912</th>
        <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Tim</th>
        <th>See</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Stockholm</th>
        <th>+44 123 5763</th>
        <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Dr</th>
        <th>Philipp</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>New York</th>
        <th>+49 241 4513</th>
        <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Max</th>
        <th>Hue</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Los Angelas</th>
        <th>+44 124 1341</th>
        <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">ID</th>
        <th class="text-center">Art</th>
        <th class="text-center">Anrede</th>
        <th class="text-center">Titel</th>
        <th class="text-center">Vorname</th>
        <th class="text-center">Name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Firma</th>
        <th class="text-center">Straße</th>
        <th class="text-center">Ort</th>
        <th class="text-center">Mobil</th>
        <th class="text-center tfoot-hide-select">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

Kind regards and Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify first the index of the grouped column then append the values to the ID column, same as filtering it by group, you need its index.

To update the select options, you need to use [`search`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()) API then on `draw` event, empty the select option values then append it with the filtered ones.

```js
var table;
var groupColumn = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {

  table = $('#contact_overview_table').DataTable({
    "displayStart": 0,
    "language": {
      "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/German.json"
    },
    "columnDefs": [{
      "visible": false,
      "targets": groupColumn
    }],
    "order": [
      [groupColumn, 'asc']
    ],
    "processing": true,
    "pageLength": 25,
    "drawCallback": function(settings) {
      var api = this.api();
      var rows = api.rows({
        page: 'current'
      }).nodes();
      var last = null;

      api.column(groupColumn, {
        page: 'current'
      }).data().each(function(group, i) {
        if (last !== group) {
          $(rows).eq(i).before(
            '<tr class="group"><td colspan="15" style="font-weight: bold;">' + group + '</td></tr>'
          );

          last = group;
        }
      });
    },
    initComplete: function() {
      var table = this;
      this.api().columns().every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
          .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
          .on('change', function() {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
              $(this).val()
            );
            if (column.index() === 0) {
              column.column([1]).search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                .draw()
            } else {
              console.log(column)
              column
                .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                .draw();
            }

          });

        if (column.index() === 0) {
          this.column([1]).data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
          }); //column.data
        } else {
          column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
          }); //column.data
        }
      });
    },
  });
  table.on('draw', function() {
    table.columns().indexes().each(function(idx) {
      var select = $(table.column(idx).footer()).find('select');
      if (select.val() === '' && idx !== 0) {
        select
          .empty()
          .append('<option value=""/>');
        table.column(idx, {
          search: 'applied'
        }).data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
        });
      }
    });
  });
  // Order by the grouping
  $('#contact_overview_table tbody').on('click', 'tr.group', function() {
    var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
    if (currentOrder[0] === groupColumn && currentOrder[1] === 'asc') {
      table.order([groupColumn, 'desc']).draw();
    } else {
      table.order([groupColumn, 'asc']).draw();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<div id="contact_overview_table_div" class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="contact_overview_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">ID</th>
        <th class="text-center">Art</th>
        <th class="text-center">Anrede</th>
        <th class="text-center">Titel</th>
        <th class="text-center">Vorname</th>
        <th class="text-center">Name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Firma</th>
        <th class="text-center">Straße</th>
        <th class="text-center">Ort</th>
        <th class="text-center">Mobil</th>
        <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Porf</th>
        <th>Max</th>
        <th>Müller</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Berlin</th>
        <th>+21 431 8912</th>
        <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Tim</th>
        <th>See</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Stockholm</th>
        <th>+44 123 5763</th>
        <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Dr</th>
        <th>Philipp</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>New York</th>
        <th>+49 241 4513</th>
        <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Max</th>
        <th>Hue</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Los Angelas</th>
        <th>+44 124 1341</th>
        <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">ID</th>
        <th class="text-center">Art</th>
        <th class="text-center">Anrede</th>
        <th class="text-center">Titel</th>
        <th class="text-center">Vorname</th>
        <th class="text-center">Name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Firma</th>
        <th class="text-center">Straße</th>
        <th class="text-center">Ort</th>
        <th class="text-center">Mobil</th>
        <th class="text-center tfoot-hide-select">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this is what I am searching for. However, the select options aren't updated after you have selected customer or supplier. Test it. Select customer and you still can see e.g. Hue in the name select... How can we update the select options?

Comment: Oh I see, you need further filtering base on the group.